# Выражение должно иметь тип класса

Tags: c++

Мне нужен вектор, который бы можно было очистить из памяти в любой момент. Вот этот код:

```
 auto *joj = new std::vector<int>;
    int j = *joj.size();
```

Выдаёт ошибку: выражение должно иметь тип класса во второй строчке. Как нужно написать в данном случае?

Answer (score 3):

```
int j = joj->size();

int j = (*joj).size();
```

Выбирайте :)

Просто приоритет точки (выбор члена) выше приоритета звездочки (разыменования).

Comment: а если нужно взять число из вектора?
joj[i]!=0

Comment: @Depth, ну хоть иногда в [документацию](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) заглядывайте... `joj->at(i) != 0`. Или вообще не создавайте вектор с помощью `new`.

Comment: `(*joj)[i]` или `joj->operator[](i)`. Если нужен именно оператор `[]`. Можно использовать `at()`, но тут минус (и он же плюс :)) в том, что там выполняется проверка выхода за границу вектора.

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что совершенно не понятно, почему вы сам объект класса `std::vector` выделяете в динамической памяти. Этот объект занимает достаточно мало памяти, обычно меньше 16 байтов независимо от того, сколько элементов он содержит.

Например, при запуске следующей демонстрационной программы, в котором объявляется объект класса `std::vector<int>` с тысячью элементов, сам объект занимает всего лишь 12 байтов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v( 1000 );
    std::cout << sizeof( v ) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
12
```

Обычно, чтобы освободить память, занимаемую вектором, используют прием с применением функции-члена класса `swap`. Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v( 1000 );

    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << ", v.size() " << v.size() << std::endl;

    std::vector<int>().swap( v );

    std::cout << "v.capacity() = " << v.capacity() << ", v.size() " << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
v.capacity() = 1000, v.size() 1000
v.capacity() = 0, v.size() 0
```

Что касается вашего фрагмента кода

```
auto *joj = new std::vector<int>;
int j = *joj.size();
```

то унарный оператор `operator *` имеет меньший приоритет, чем постфиксная операция вызова функции, а вам нужно как раз сначала применить оператор разыменования к указателю.

Поэтому вы можете написать либо как

```
int j = ( *joj ).size();
```

либо как

```
int j = joj->size();
```

Имейте в виду, что тип `int` выбран неправильно для хранения результата, возвращаемого функцией `size`. Он может быть не способен представлять все значения, возвращаемые этой функцией. Поэтому по крайней мере было бы лучше опять-таки применить спецификатор типа `auto` в объвлении переменной. Например

```
auto j = joj->size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
int j = (*joj).size();
```